# Render specific header for specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to RoR and using layouts/partials/rendering, all that good stuff, to make an app.  At the beginning of my app I thought I would use the same header for the entire app, and thus wrote:

```
render 'layouts/header'
```

in my `application.html.erb` file.  Now, I realized that for certain pages (i.e. sign up page and blog) I want to use a simplified header called `simple_header`.  Do I write something like

```
<%= if @simple_header
        render 'layouts/simple_header'
    else 
        render 'layouts/header' 
%>
```

and then test if `@simple_header` is true or something in a controller, or is there a better way to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails, you can create different layouts and choose which one to use for a particular action or a controller.

Watch this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts

That should help you solve your problem.

For example.,

Create a new layout in `app/views/layouts`, say, `simple_header.html.erb` and in your controller, tell it to use that layout.

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
 layout :simple_header

 def index
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Also (if you have simple logic) consider using

> current_page?

method like this:

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'sites', action: 'index') %>
...
<% else %>
...
<% end%>
```